# Javascript popup , html, php

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a pop up window onclick event of both button and link. All is working fine but it opens a blank window when the page loads.I don't need it on loading , i just need the popup on click. can anybody help me?
my code is below:

```
function OpenWin()
{
    window.open('../test.php','test','width=500,height=300,scrollbars=1');
return false;
}
```

the html for this is:

```
<input type="text" name="tst" value="<?php echo $editData['somefield'];?>"/>&nbsp;<a href='#' onClick="javascript:return OpenWin();">Test</a> <input type="button" value="Test" onClick="return OpenWin();">
```

Comment: Please, post more from your html code.

Comment: nothing else for this pop up. only the given html is

Comment: please click the checkbox if one of these answers was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. the keyword `javascript:` is not necessary at attribute `onClick`
2. Does the page `test.php` give any HTML code back to the browser? If not, no wonder why a blank page will be displayed.

Comment: I agree with GlitchMr answer. All things looks fine. Because we cannot see your complete code, I think there must be something wrong with your php page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="tst" value="<?php echo $editData['somefield'];?>"/>&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:OpenWin();">Test</a> 
<input type="button" value="Test" onClick="OpenWin();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2cPqa/1/

Comment: add this function to your javascript, function open()
{

}     Now it will not work. what's the problem?

Comment: <script>function OpenWin()
{
    window.open('../test.php','test','width=500,height=300,scrollbars=1');
return false;
}</script>
<input type="text" name="tst" value="<?php echo $editData['somefield'];?>"/>&nbsp;<a href='#' onClick="OpenWin();">Test</a> <input type="button" value="Test" onClick="OpenWin();">

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>function OpenWin()
{
    window.open('../test.php','test','width=500,height=300,scrollbars=1');
return false;
}</script>
<input type="text" name="tst" value="<?php echo $editData['somefield'];?>"/>&nbsp;<a href='#' onClick="OpenWin();">Test</a> <input type="button" value="Test" onClick="OpenWin();">
```

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/WlbTxw.php53

Should work, unless you use that script in `<iframe>` for some reason.

Hint: There really shouldn't be "result".

Comment: not working.actually on my page there is a another javascript function

Comment: function(){} this doesn't allow the popup to display, when i comment it, and refresh the page, first a blank window popsup and then onclick it works. i don't need that blank window on load